# Python multiprocessing: how to delete a managed dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a dictionary managed by `SyncManager` and I'm using the `.get()` and `.update()` functions to retrieve and set dictionary keys and values. However, the `del dict[key]` method is not implemented. Is there a way to delete a key from a managed dictionary key?

Simple example:

```
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
shared_dict = mgr.dict()

shared_dict.update( {'key1' : 'value1'} )
print shared_dict.get('key1')

#Now let's delete key1
del shared_dict['key1']  #Nope!
shared_dict.__delitem__('key1')  #Also not allowed
```

Comment: did you try `shared_dict.pop('key1')` ? -- I'm just guessing here ...

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Does your example fail as written? It works for me as is in 2.7.2 and 3.2.2.

Comment: Also, rather than comments like #Nope! it's more helpful to paste the exact response you get from the interpreter.

Comment: Works for me. Your test case seems incomplete.